# How to match elements of row with elements of a column and perform calculations on them in rstudio

Tags: r, for-loop, match, rstudio

I want to match the columnname "Name" from dataframe List to the Rowname of dataframe "Volume" and perform calultion on the columns.

Can I use the match or row.match for this purpose.

I am trying to do something like this

```
Total <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
for (i in 1:5) 
{
  print(List$S.No[i] * 100)
  for (j in 1:5) 
    {
    if (match(List$Name, colnames(Volume)), 2]))
    Value = Total + Volume[j]
    print(Value)
    }
}
print(Total)
```

Problem with the code:

```
Total <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
for (i in 1:5) 
{
  print(List$S.No[i] * 100)
  for (j in 1:5) 
    {
    if (match(List$Name, colnames(Volume)), 2]))
    # This match condition is not correct. I do not know how to call the column header
    Value = Total + Volume[i]
    # I want to add the data from the matching column to Total
    print(Value)
    }
 }
print(Total)
```

I want to read the first element in List$Name match with the corresponding column, extract the column and perform a simple addition on it and store the result in the dataframe "Total". I want the same thing to be done for all the elements in the row individually.

```html
List

S.No Name
2 Ba
1 Ar
5 Ca
3 Bl
4 Bu

Volume

Ar Ba Bl Bu Ca 
-5.1275 1.3465 -1.544 -0.0877 3.2955 
-2.2385 1.5065 0.193 1.082 3.074 
-5.3705 1.1285 1.966 1.183 -1.9305 
-6.4925 1.5735 1.36 -0.0761 2.0875 
-5.068 0.9455 0.947 -0.7775 3.832
```

I know this can be done after merging the two files and using a sapply function. But since I wanna use a for loop on the dataframe "List" I just want to compare the two dataframes and store the results separately to another dataframe everytime after a loop is over. So merging the files doesn't help solve this.

The actual List dataframe consists of 23 records and the actual Volume dataframe consists of 18000 records.

I am trying to build a function but am not sure as a for loop is necessary for this calculation. Is there a better and easier way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem faced in this question matching a row element to that of a column using the code

```
match(List$Name[i], names(Volume))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have understood your answer. 
I think you have to correct your code in this way:

```
for (i in 1: length(List$Name)) {
    for (j in 1:dim(Volume)[2]) {
        if(List$Name[i]==colnames(Volume[j])) Total[,i]<-Total[,i]+Volume[,j]
    }
```

}

Comment: The code has some error.    Error in if (List_Sample$Name[i] == colnames(Volume[, j])) Total[, i] <- Total[,  : 
  argument is of length zero. I am not sure what the error means.

Comment: Sorry! if(List$Name[i]==colnames(Volume[j])) . Remove ' , ' in colnames(Volume[,j]))

Comment: Even then doesnt work. Error in `[.data.frame`(Total, , i) : undefined columns selected this is the error. I think it is the problem with the looping.

Comment: I have solved the problem faced in this question matching a row element to a column using match(List$Name[i], names(Volume))